# How do I concatenate lines from a file onto a single line of code?

Tags: python

I'm new to programming and currently working on problem  [#269 from r/dailyprogrammer.](https://www.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer/comments/4lpygb/20160530_challenge_269_easy_basic_formatting/) I want to add the ability to read files and format them based on the indention format given. My current code:

```
import sys

filename=input("What file would you like to reformat?")
f=open(filename,"r")
n_lines= int(f.readline())
indents=(f.readline())

block=0
for line in f:
    line=line.lstrip('·» \t')
    if line.startswith('ENDIF') or line.startswith('NEXT'):
        block-=1
    print(indents*block+line)
    if line.startswith('FOR') or line.startswith('IF'):
        block+=1
```

gives me this

```
VAR I

FOR I=1 TO 31

····
IF !(I MOD 3) THEN

····
····
PRINT "FIZZ"

····
ENDIF

····
IF !(I MOD 5) THEN

····
····
PRINT "BUZZ"

····
ENDIF

····
IF (I MOD 3) && (I MOD 5) THEN

····
····
PRINT "FIZZBUZZ"

····
ENDIF

NEXT
```

,but I want it to print the pseudo indentions+line on the same line.

Comment: What is the input of your file? I feel like there is code missing. Also, maybe give a smaller example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `indents` string ends with a newline, like this: `"    \n"`. You want to get rid of that.

```
indents=f.readline().strip('\n')
```

When reading from a text file, there will always be a newline character at the end of each line until you've reached the end of the file.

`print()` will also add a single newline to its output by default. If you don't want that, you can pass an `end` argument.

```
print('this line doesn't need another newline.\n', end='')
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it was killing me haha.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement `print(indents*block+line)` inherently adds a new line character at the end. Since the python "print" statement adds newline regardless of whats inside the print command.
Add a comma at the end of the print statement like this `print(indents*block+line,)` and it will not print the newline character.

Comment: Thanks RJM you were right about the problem, but that solution didn't work for me.

Comment: @lzzino there's another way you can suppress the newline, try `print(indents*block+line, end=" ")`, this will end the `print` statement with a space rather then newline.

Answer (score -1):

Just use multiple lines string in your program as an input.

inputBasicCode = """

...

'"""

It is more simple and clear way to do program input. Perfect for debugging. Just concentrate on the target.

[More details of the task is on Reddit.com site](https://www.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer/comments/4lpygb/20160530_challenge_269_easy_basic_formatting/)